# Printf() not working while Converting string to morze in C

Tags: c, printf, converters

I am beginner on C programming. I have written program to converting string to morze alphabetical string with dots and dashes. But printf() not working. Am I writing something wrong?(honestly this program for using processor ATMega. But main problem in my code, so don't pay attention it)

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{   
char morze[] = "";
char buf[] ="Name Surname Patronymic";
int a = 0;
char *p = strtok (buf, " ");
char *each_word[3];

while (p != NULL)
{
    each_word[a++] = p;
    p = strtok (NULL, " ");
}

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(each_word); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < strlen(each_word[i]); j++){
        if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "a") strcat(morze,".- ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "b") strcat(morze,"-... ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "c") strcat(morze,"-.-. ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "d") strcat(morze,"-.. ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "e") strcat(morze,". ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "f") strcat(morze,"..-. ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "g") strcat(morze,"--. ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "h") strcat(morze,".... ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "i") strcat(morze,".. ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "j") strcat(morze,".--- ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "k") strcat(morze,"-.- ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "l") strcat(morze,".-.. ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "m") strcat(morze,"-- ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "n") strcat(morze,"-. ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "o") strcat(morze,"--- ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "p") strcat(morze,".--. ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "q") strcat(morze,"--.- ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "r") strcat(morze,".-. ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "s") strcat(morze,"... ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "t") strcat(morze,"- ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "u") strcat(morze,"..- ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "v") strcat(morze,"...- ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "w") strcat(morze,".-- ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "x") strcat(morze,"-..- ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "y") strcat(morze,"-.-- ");
        else if(tolower(each_word[i][j]) == "z") strcat(morze,"--.. ");
    }
}

printf(buf);

int b = 0;
char *q = strtok (morze, " ");
char *each_letter[3];

while (q != NULL)
{
    each_letter[b++] = q;
    q = strtok (NULL, " ");
}

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(each_letter); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < strlen(each_letter[i]); j++){
        if(each_letter[i][j] == ".") {printf("1");}
        else if(each_letter[i][j] == "-") {printf("2");}
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything you do is wrong bcause `morze` is not large enough to concatenate to it, try with

```
char morze[100 /* Large enough size */] = "";
```

instead.

As it is the default behavior is to allocate an array of size 1 containing a single byte `'\0'`, such array cannot be resized.

Also, string comparison is not done with the `==` operator in [c](/questions/tagged/c), you need to use `strcmp()` to compare two strings. But you don't need to anyway as you want to compare single characters, instead

```
switch (character) {
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
    case ...:
       break;
}
```